# Why sqlite3-ruby would not install on show leopard

Tags: rubygems

I am trying to help a friend to install RoR 2.3.8
We started with his laptop having Ruby 1.8.5 and installed Macports. Then updated gem framework and used Macports to install Sqlite3 and Ruby 1.8.7
Finally we are trying to do 
`sudo gem install sqlite3-ruby` and getting and error stating "sqlite3-ruby requires Ruby version >= 1.8.7". 
At the same time if I type "ruby -v" I do get a confirmation that 1.8.7 is running. Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to install the gem w/o `sudo`?